# wfs feature onSelect event not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to load features from WFS source, click on the feature and get a popup showing info of this feature.
My code is like this:

```
` var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
  renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;
  featureLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS点图层", {
    version: "1.1.0",
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url: "http://172.31.4.122:8090/iserver/services/data-XinDiTu/wfs100/utf-8",
    featureType: "BaseMap_P",
    featureNS: "http://www.supermap.com/newdata",
    featurePrefix:"newdata"
    }),
    renderers: renderer,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()]
    });
    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
  var click = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(featureLayer, { onSelect: createPopup,         onUnselect: destroyPopup })
  map.addControl(click);
  click.activate();'
```

This works fine in Internet Explore, but not in firefox or Chrome (no response when click on the feature).
I wonder whether it relates to the cross rigion access, but I use the proxy.cgi, and it works.

So anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is no errors or other information when I debug in Chrome or firefox.

Comment: It turns out that the selecting not response is because there are multi-layers. Besides this WFS feature layer, I also add another vector layer in this map, and add select feature control to this layer. When I remove this layer, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple vector layers, add them all to your SelectFeature control. See http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html

In your case:

```
var click = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([featureLayer, otherFeatureLayer], { onSelect: createPopup,         onUnselect: destroyPopup })
```